# KeyError with a String Python

Tags: python

im using a FSM and have a Problem with a Key...

```
class SimpleFSM(object):
    def __init__(self, char):
        self.char = char
        self.states = {}
        self.transitions = {}
        self.curState = None
        self.trans = None

    def SetState(self,stateName):
        self.curState = self.states[stateName]

    def Transition(self, transName):
        self.trans = self.transitions[transName]

    def Execute(self):
        if(self.trans):
            self.trans.Execute()
            self.SetState(self.trans.toState)
            self.trans = None
        self.curState.Execute()
```

this is my init for the keys:

```
light.FSM.states["On"] = LightOn()
light.FSM.states["Off"] = LightOff()
light.FSM.transitions["toOn"] = Transition("On")
light.FSM.transitions["toOff"] = Transition("Off")
```

i can change the state if i use:

```
light.FSM.Transition("toOff")
```

but why it doesnt work if i use a String with "toOff" ?

```
lightOn = "toOff"
light.FSM.Transition(lightOn)
```

sry im a rookie and not much experience with Python.

Comment: solution was just to restart python. DOnt know why it works now. How can i delete my Question?